# Chat support plugin?

Tags: plugins, support

I've been looking for a chat support plugin for WP and I haven't been able to find one, does anyone know about one? Free or paid doesn't matter.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a "talk with a representative" type chat plugin I found that www.oggchat.com was a reasonable one, and they have a Wordpress plugin to go with it. It supports the rep chatting from either the Oggchat website or via Gtalk, so your rep could be anywhere at any time, with a smartphone and a Gtalk program.

If it's a "users on the site can chat together", then Oggchat isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: also looks nice!

Answer (score 1):

[Mibew](http://mibew.org/) Messenger (also known as Open Web Messenger) is an open-source live support application written in PHP and MySQL. It enables one-on-one chat assistance in real-time directly from your website.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried A LOT but ... in the end I found 123Chat the the most professional: http://www.123flashchat.com/ / http://www.123flashchat.com/live-help-chat.html worked very well on my BuddyPress / Multisite community.

(Enterprise ready versus all the others which are 'smaller business ready or even use for non professional use only'). They have a lot of different applets and products and plugins and are the most comprehensive, just check their business partner list: ibm etc..

However, they were also the most expensive BUT.. cool things, developer platform, running the java server on your own server or hosted, apps for mobile applications and from rooms to chatbar to whatever it's in there and they can customize and setup everything. Went very smoothly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your recommendation, could you also tell me the other options you have tried? I found 123flashchat rather pricey for what I'm trying to do. It doesn't need to be a full featured chat support, only the very basics.

Comment: You said 'free or paid does not matter'... Among others Bowob (directchat) (but was heavy on socket usage), cometchat (which i bought for 150+dollar and then then let them do the buddypress/multisite integration) since i wanted integration with my userbase but as stated below also used as 'users on the site can chat together'.

Comment: Indeed, but didn't meant price doesn't matter :)

Answer (score -2):

WordPress is an great content management system (CMS) to successfully publish online content. By live chat interface you can  easily interact with web visitors and customer, ensure them have great experience when they use your services. Therefore, eAssistance Pro provides chat plugin for WordPress powered website, it's fully customizable and compatible as per users needs.

Get setup from here https://www.eassistancepro.com/addons/wordpress.php

Comment: This reads more like advertisment than answer. Please disclose your affiliation if you are involved with the product.